# How to create an account on phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a site at a hosting service and I want to work with phpmyAdmin. I copied the phpmyAdmin files in `public_html`. I entered `www.mywebsite.com/phpmyAdmin`, but
it required a username and a password. How to create an account?

Comment: at your host's admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

Login your machine, and try this

```
$ mysql -u root -p

mysql> CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Replace `newuser` and `password` with yours.

Answer (score 0):

If you used cPanel.

Login to your cPanel => Find Database => phpMyAdmin and click it, if you still got error you need to try asking the problem to your **Host Provider**.

Then if you want to access it from `domain.com/phpmyadmin` directly in the future, you can check your user account from `User accounts` on your phpMyAdmin navigation bar.

Then you can create a new user using `Add new Account`. After that, you can access your phpMyAdmin directly from `domain.com/phpmyadmin` without login to cPanel

And you can try to change your `domain.com/phpmyadmin` into `domain.com/something`, so other people will not easily access your **phpMyAdmin**

Comment: I created an user with cPanel but I don't have acces to create a database. I want create an account using phpMyAdmin files. Existing a way?

Comment: Actually you can access phpMyAdmin directly from cPanel. Open your cPanel then find Database menu, click on phpMyAdmin. After you get in to the phpMyAdmin, find `User accounts` on top navbar then `Add new account` or `Edit privileges` so you will have access to your phpMyAdmin without accessing cPanel. Still get Error ?

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using Cpanel. There is a option for accessing into your database by Phpmyadmin. Just Click on that. If you failed to get that. Then contact with your host provider regarding this issue.